# CONTAINS does not work with ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT 
    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) 
    , ID
    , Name
 FROM 
    Clients
  WHERE
    CONTAINS (Name, 'Jose')
```

My client table has a single record with the name "Jose", so this query returns only one record. When I try to execute the query I get a timeout:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) 
            , ID
            , Name
        FROM 
            Clients WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE
            CONTAINS (Name, 'Jose')
    ) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE
    RowNumber >= 1 AND RowNumber <= 2
```

However, if I change the `WHERE` clause as below, it works:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) 
            , ID
            , Name
        FROM 
            Clients WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE
            CONTAINS (Name, 'Jose')
    ) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE
    RowNumber >= 1 AND RowNumber <= 1
```

I concluded that if the number of records returned by the query is less than the range I need, I will have problems. Does anyone know why? Is my conclusion is right?

Comment: Where do you define `Indice`? Also try to eliminate some variables, e.g. full-text search. Do you get the same behavior if you bypass the FT index and just use `=` or `LIKE` to return the same row?

Comment: Sorry, it's not Indice, is the correct RowNumber.

Comment: Also what is the purpose of `WHERE RowNumber >= 1`? I don't think it will change the outcome, but you really only need the `<=` if you're starting at the beginning of the range, since by definition every `ROW_NUMBER()` will be >= 1. And if you're using pagination and are on SQL Server 2012 or better, you should look into `OFFSET / FETCH`.

Comment: And please, when the query is "timing out" - check `sys.dm_exec_requests` and see what it's waiting on. Maybe it's blocked by something.

Comment: The purpose is to make paging to exemplify put RowNumber> = 1 but depending on the page the user wants to be> = the other number. I am working with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64).

Comment: And is there a covering index to make the ROW_NUMBER() calculation simple? (The only way I can see a difference in plans or performance at all is if `ID` is in an index, but not the leading key of the clustered index.) What is the structure of the table, including the clustered and any non-clustered indexes? How many rows in the table?